# Find my own latest check ins using FQL and javascript sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My question is how do I my own latest check ins from face book. Well I am open to graph api or fql. I already know how to find my friends but I can't find my own.

me/friends?fields=checkins.limit(1) this gives me my friends but when I tried me?fields=checkins.limit(1) , I dont get any data back , though I have checked in to various places.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Jossie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : `me?fields=posts.fields(place)`

> Publishing a Checkin object is deprecated in favor of creating a Post with a location attached.

Comment: thanks @Sebastien , u are awesome .. that works  ! me?fields=posts.fields.place too works :).

Answer (score 0):

me?fields=posts.with(location).fields(place) , yeah this was the exact answer I was looking for, I got this as I was playing with explorer tool of facebook.

Cheers and happy coding.
Jossie